# Basic LCM problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $g_1$, $g_2$, $g_3$ are the GCMs and $l_1$, $l_2$, $l_3$ are the LCMs of $b$ and $c$,  $c$ and $a$,  $a$ and $b$ respectively, $G$ the GCM and $L$ the LCM of the three $a$, $b$, $c$, show that

$$L=\frac{abcG}{g_{1}g_{2}g_{3}}$$

Edit: This is an exercise from an elementary textbook, so I've decided to add the tag "homework". However it was not actually assigned as homework (to me or anyone that I know); I am reading through Chrystal's $Algebra$ on my own and do not know anyone that I can ask for help.

Edit: Solved.

Comment: Seems like a homework question! what've you tried out so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think by "GCM" you mean "GCD". To show that two positive integers are equal, it suffices to prove that every prime $p$ divides both to the same power. Let $p(a)$ be the highest exponents $d$ for which  $p^d$ divides $a $, and similarly for other numbers. By relabeling  $a,b,c$ we may assume $p(a)\le p(b)\le p(c)$. (The formula we are to prove does not change when the numbers are permuted).  Then 
$$p(L ) = \max(p(a),p(b),p(c)) = p(c)$$
$$p(G) = \min(p(a),p(b),p(c)) = p(a)$$
$$p(g_1)=\min(p(b),p(c))=p(b)$$ $$p(g_2)=\min(p(a),p(c))=p(a)$$ $$p(g_3)=\min(p(a),p(b))=p(a)$$ 
Therefore,
$$p\left(\frac{abcG}{p_1p_2p_3}\right) = p(a)+p(b)+p(c)+p(a)-p(b)-p(a)-p(a) = p(c)$$
which is equal to $p(L)$.